# Should I use pip or setuptools for my python project

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

So far I have used pip and virtualenv for my python projects without any problems.

But is there any advantage ( functionalities, speed, more-structured, easily-maintainable, cross-platform etc ) of using setuptools over pip or vice-versa. Which one should I use and why? What I basically understand from my research is setuptools is used when you want to distribute your python code as packages and it handles dependencies, metadata , resources through egg.

It would be great if you can explain in what kind of scenario/ projects we should use pip and setuptools. And if there is any better alternative of pip or setuptools?